# How to display image in Tkinter on the fly?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I've written a snippet of code to display images in a Tkinter app. However, the image does not display unless I read all of the images before assigning it to the label. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
root.title("Image Viewer app")


def readImage(image_name):
    my_img = Image.open(image_name)
    my_img = my_img.resize((640, 360), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(my_img)
    return my_img

frame_lst = list(range(0,120))
img_lst = []
path = "usr/data/images"

start = time.time()
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.jpg'):
        filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
        img_lst.append(filepath) #print time taken
end = time.time()
print(f"Time taken to read images is {end-start} seconds")
    
image_displayed = Label(image=readImage(img_lst[0]))
image_displayed.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

This does not work but if I replace `img_lst.append(filepath)` with `img_lst.append(imageRead(filepath))` and `image_displayed = Label(image=readImage(img_lst[0]))` with `image_displayed = Label(image=img_lst[0])`  then it works.

That is, the app does not work when I try to read the image directly without preloading it in memory. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no variable to store the reference of the image returned by `readImage()` in the following line:

```py
image_displayed = Label(image=readImage(img_lst[0]))
```

the image will be garbage collected.  Use a variable to store the reference, like below:

```py
image = readImage(img_lst[0]) # save the reference of the image
image_displayed = Label(image=image)
```